# how to find two pair that the sum is same as given value in BST?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find two pair that the sum of them are same as given number in binary search tree but, I don't get correct answer , please someone help me. My code is below:

```
void BST::find_sum(node * root1,node * root2,int sum)
{
if(root1==NULL)
    return;
if(root2==NULL)
{
    return;
}

 if((root1->data+root2->data)==sum)
 {
     if(root1==root2)
         return;
     cout<<"\t "<<root1->data<<" + "<<root2->data<<" = "<<sum;
     return;
 }

     find_sum(root1,root2->left,sum);
     find_sum(root1,root2->right,sum);

     return;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this:

```
 find_sum(root1,root2->right,sum);
 find_sum(root1,root2->left,sum);
```